# Why bounded linear operators on Hilbert space are defined on the whole space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I've read different references about bounded operators but some are unclear with what they used and others justify but I'm unable to figure out where it comes.

They defined that a linear operator $T: H \to K$, with $H$ and $K$ two Hilbert Spaces, is bounded if $D(T)=H$ ($D(T)$ is the domain of $T$) and $$\sup \{\|Tx\|\ | \|x\|\le 1\} < \infty.$$

The point that bothers me is that $D(T) = H$, some justify it by the fact a bounded linear operator can be extended to $\overline{D(T)}$ and that $D(T)$ is dense in $H$ so we can always work with operator defined everywhere because all the others can be extended to $H$. But why $D(T)$ is dense in $H$ ? Is there the result which states that ? A reference says that most of the operators we use are densely defined, may be they assume that we only work with this kind of operators.

I can solve my problem by thinking that we only use densely or everywhere defined operator but the problem resurfaces when we talk about inverse of a bounded operators. If an operator $T: H \to H$ is 1-1 when can talk about $T^{-1}$ with $D(T^{-1}) = \text{im}(T)$ but I think there is not reason for $T^{-1}$ to be densely or everywhere defined. Then they present the following result :
$$T \text{ has a bounded inverse iff } T \text{ is bijective}$$
But what does they mean by inverse ? A everywhere defined inverse ? I have difficulties to prove $\Rightarrow$ because I don't really know what's the definition of bounded inverse.

Here are the references I read :

- Spectral Theory of Operators on Hilbert space, A. D. Andrew and W. L. Green, 2002
- A primary introduction to spectral theory, lecture from Jianwei Yang in 2019.
- Wikipedia and forums.

Comment: There is no real reason to require anything less than dense domain, since you would just naturally take any operator to be associated with the closure of its domain. Operationally, having a dense domain is the minimal requirement for an extension to $H$ to be _unique_ when it exists. It is also a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a unique Hilbert adjoint. All of these reasons are motivation to require dense domain as a part of the definition of a linear operator. Since bounded operators can always be extended to $H$, you might as well define them to have domain $H$.

Comment: As for the inverse, it is the usual sense. Any injective function has an inverse when restricted to its range, but that's not typically what we mean by the term "inverse", which requires inversion with respect to the entire codomain. The key part of the "bounded inverse" statement is in fact the bounded part. Maybe you will appreciate it more in a topological sense (remember bounded = continuous). A bijective continuous function is not generally required to have a _continuous_ inverse. The bounded inverse theorem tells you that such pathologies cannot happen for linear operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer !